# Changing the look of payment options on a Website? Identity-Guidelines

Tags: copyright

On my website I'm displaying the available payment options on the main shop page. 
It's just there to inform the visitor; there is no interaction with these icons.
I changed the look of them to fit the design of my site better.

Most of these companies have **strict Identity-Guidelines** that don't allow these changes.

**Does posting these modified images violate copyright law?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes: images are implicitly protected by copyright.  If the owners of those images allow you to use them *only under a license that prohibits the modifications you have proposed* then you are violating their copyright.  (And you don't even posit a [fair-use](/questions/tagged/fair-use) exemption to their copyright.)